# Why atoi function returns -1 when giving LONG_MAX

Tags: string, memory, system, atoi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        printf("%d\n", atoi("9223372036854775807"));
        printf("%d\n", atoi("9223372036854775"));
        return (0);
}
```

This code gaves me those outputs:

```
-1
-1511828489
```

But why? How atoi function detects this difference?

Comment: atoi works with int, you need atol

Comment: I know but why atoi acting like this? Its returns -1 only for bigger or equal values than LONG_MAX. What's the implementation in the standard C library?

Comment: `If the converted value would be out of the range of representable values by an int, it causes undefined behavior.` so it can return anything

Comment: BTW, this implementation returns lowest 32 bit of real long 64 bit result

Comment: I think it's enough for me :) Thanks!